# In C how many bytes of memory are occupied by an array of 100 float variables and an array of 100 character pointers?

Tags: c

bool:   1 bytes
char:   1 bytes
short:  2 bytes
int:    4 bytes
long:   8 bytes
float:  4 bytes
double: 8 bytes
long double:    16 bytes
unsigned int:   8 bytes
unsigned char:  1 bytes
long int:   8 bytes
short int:  2 bytes
signed char:    1bytes

Comment: Answer varies with platform. C doesn't specify the size of a float or a pointer to char (though `sizeof` will tell you the size for any particular implementation).

Comment: use the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: Your table doesn't contain the pointer size, so you weren't given enough information to make the determination.

Comment: an int is 4 bytes but an unsigned int is 8? That's not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

Why not try it for yourself

```
float a[100];
char* b[100];
printf("size of 100 floats = %zu\n", sizeof(a));
printf("size of 100 char pointers = %zu\n", sizeof(b));
```

Comment: `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, but `%d` tells `printf` that you're passing an `int`. The mismatch gives undefined behavior.

Comment: You should cast the `size_t` value obtained from `sizeof` (`printf("%d", (int)sizeof a);` or `printf("%u", (unsigned)sizeof a);`) or use the C99 `%zu` specifier (`printf("%zu", sizeof b)`).

Comment: @pmg Thanks, updated as suggested

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use `sizeof()` operator.

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).